# Is the leaderboard mandatory for a game to be accepted?

Tags: ios, iphone

My app has just been rejected for the following reason:

> 10.6
>
> We found the following issues with the user interface of your app:
>
> - Did not integrate with iOS features. **For example, the leaderboard should integrate with Game Center**.
>
> These examples identify types of issues discovered in your app but may
>   not represent all such issues. It would be appropriate to thoroughly
>   evaluate your app to address these types of issues.

I don't have any leaderboard in my game, just a score at the end of every turn.

Is the leaderboard mandatory?

Answer (score 2):

[Please refer the attached screenshot which was taken from apple documentation.](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/GameKit_Guide/GameCenterOverview/GameCenterOverview.html)

[image]

Comment: I'm planning on adding it soon. But if it's optional, why would they reject my game for it?

Comment: may be it should be a multi player game or they could consider other factors.

Answer (score 1):

The best thing to do is just add the leaderboard, and integrate it to the Game Center.

On the other hand, there may be other reasons for the rejection, the Game Center integration is just an example. If you do sound without using Core Audio, they would reject you too, etc

Comment: Thank you for the reply. What other examples can there be?